# как сделать фильтр слов но при этом что бы буквы работали в разнобой

Tags: javascript, node.js, поиск, фильтры

как сделать фильтр слов но при этом что бы буквы работали в разнобой
то-есть все буквы что есть в этом слове отдавал **true**

```
'testWordForSearch'.match('ts')
```

а вот так уже **false**

```
'testWordForSearch'.match('tsu')
```

так же приветствуются модули  **nodejs**

**match** я использовал просто для примера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, можно так:

```js
function checkLetters(text, letters) {
  return [...letters].every(letter => text.includes(letter));
}


console.log(checkLetters('testWordForSearch', 'ts'));
console.log(checkLetters('testWordForSearch', 'tsu'));
```

Или даже так (нужно ещё проверить, какой вариант быстрее и есть ли вообще существенная разница для вашего случая):

```js
function checkLetters(text, letters) {
  text = new Set(text);
  return [...letters].every(letter => text.has(letter));
}

console.log(checkLetters('testWordForSearch', 'ts'));
console.log(checkLetters('testWordForSearch', 'tsu'));
```